# Calculating distance of closest pair of $n$ points in unit square

Tags: algorithms

> There are $n$ points are placed in a unit square. Show that the distance between the closest pair is $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$.

My intuition is that the solution would involve using divide-and-conquer, but I'm not certain how to approach it. I have been given the hint to "divide the unit square into $n-1$ smaller squares", but I fail to see how this helps.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem.

Comment: The text hints that the points need to be in a unit square, but you did not make this explicit.  Please state your question clearly.  I suspect you are asking "If $n$ points are placed in the unit square, prove that there are two within (some distance)"

Comment: @JKow77:  your edit has removed the text I was asking for. Rolling back.

Answer (score 3):

Take an $m \times m$ grid of squares, where $m^2 < n \le (m+1)^2$.  Pigeonhole principle says at least two points are in the same square.  And then their distance is at most ...

Comment: $m^2 < n$ is not a problem, what happens when $n < (m+1)^2$ ? Certainly there are $(m+1)^2 - n$ more squares than points, how do you apply pigeonhole principle then ?

Comment: No, there are $m^2$ squares.  $m^2 < n$ means there are more points than squares.

Comment: I was thinking about a grid of $(m+1) * (m+1)$, however even in case of $m * m$ grid, side of small square would be $1/m$. Since $m^2<n$ implying $1/\sqrt n<1/m$. As max distance 2 points in a square can be at is diagonal length so the upper bound would be $\sqrt 2/m$. And since we already saw $1/\sqrt n<1/m$, max distance is not bounded by $O(1/\sqrt(n)$

Comment: $n < (m+1)^2 \le 4 m^2$, so $\sqrt{2}/m < 2 \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{n} = O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: You're right, it seems that this distance is actually $\Theta(1/\sqrt n)$.